# Office VBA method parameters (powershell)

Tags: vba, powershell, methods, parameters

I am creating a script to manipulate some PowerPoint presentation files.  One of the methods I need to use is the createvideo method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.createvideo

The above link show the parameters and their type, but I don't know what the ranges are

e.g.

Quality is INT, but is it 1-100?  I don't really want to find out through trial and error!

Is there a really easy way to find out this information.

Below is a snippet of the script I am running

```
$powerpoint = New-Object -comobject powerpoint.Application
$powerpoint.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue

$powerpoint.Presentations.Open("C:\temp\file.ppt")
$SavePath = "C:\temp\Presentation.mp4"
$powerpoint.ActivePresentation.CreateVideo($savepath,$true,"",1540,30)
```

The 30 is the quality parameter.

Thoughts welcome.

Sam

Comment: If you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.createvideo), you will find that quality is the 6th parameter and that parameters 3,4,5 and 6 are all INT, and yes, `Quality` is a percentage, so 1-100

Comment: Cool, I've missed off the last parameter ‍♂️!  Do you know if there is a way to find out what the potential values for INT parameters

Comment: I think the link I put in the comment explains the meaning of these as well

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that link before and I did put it in my original post.  I just didn't know if there was a way to find out the valid parameter values for this and other methods going forward